# How to hide files in sdcard when device is mounted

Tags: android

I am very new to android. Can any one please help me to 
find out how to hide or protect a folder from viewing when 
the device is mounted. Because my folder contains some pdf
and image files that shouldn't be seen outside other that 
from my application.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can store them on the Internal Storage to make them private.
See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal for a quick guide, and further reading.

Answer (score 0):

I think, as long as you save data to the SD card you are not able to hide that data in any way. The user is still able to take out the card and put it into a card reader to do (nasty) stuff. So it might be good to save data that you want to be hidden in the application specific folder on the device.

Read more: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal